# Как написать реализацию метода шаблонного класса, который возвращает результатом работы объект вложенного класса?

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Вопрос по синтаксису с++. Есть шаблонный класс, внутри которого инкапсулирован другой класс. Как объявить реализацию метода, который результатом своей работы возвращает объект инкапсулированного класса?(объявление и реализация в одном .h файле).

```
template<class T>
    class tree
    {
    private:
       struct node
        {
            node* left;
            node* right;
            T inf;
            node(T inf);
            ~node();
        };
    -
    -
    -
 node* search(T inf, node* current); //метод, который нужно реализовать
```

я пытплся объявить так, но ничего не выходит(ошибка /home/anton/Programming/tree/tree.h:83: ошибка: missing 'typename' prior to dependent type name 'tree::node'):

```
template<class T>
tree<T>::node* tree<T>::search(T inf, node* current)
{

}
```

Comment: *ничего не выходит* - это не описание проблемы

Comment: @AlexF, они оба приватные, добавление tree<T>:: к аргументам не помогло

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте написать

```
template<class T>
typename tree<T>::node* tree<T>::search(T inf, node* current)
```